# Html.AntiForgeryToken not working with Azure Function Proxy

Tags: azure, azure-functions, antiforgerytoken

I have an login page that uses AntiforgeryToken like this (using dojo framework form):

```
...
<div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="@formId" data-dojo-id="@formId"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Access/Login" method="post">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
...
```

The app is hosted in Azure as an app service and has a url like `myUiApp-production.azurewebsites.com`.

I also have an Azure Function app using proxy settings to map from a custom url (`myUrl.com`) to the app service. This was set up because we intend to move more functionality into the function app over time. Also, we have some legacy API functionality that was hosted as a sub-app in the UI app service, which has now been separated into a discreet app service. The proxy looks something like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "Redirect - Api": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/api/{*all}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://myApiApp-production.azurewebsites.com/{all}"
        },
        "Redirect - Api (legacy)": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/apiv1/{*all}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://myApiApp-production.azurewebsites.com/{all}"
        },
        "Redirect - UI": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/{*all}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://myUiApp-production.azurewebsites.com/{all}"
        }
    }
}
```

The proxy generally works great. When I navigate to `myUrl.com`, I am greeted with the landing page of `myUiApp` as I expect. I can click a link to move to the **/Access/Login** page and operate normally. All of the api endpoints also function correctly.

My issue is that when I navigate directly to `myUrl.com/Access/Login`, the AntiForgeryToken logic does not appear to run (i.e. I do not get a **__RequestVerificationToken** cookie in my browser). What is curious is that if I simply refresh the page, the cookie is created and works as expected. I am trying to figure out why the cookie is not generated on first load, but appears on reload.

I included the information about the proxy because when I navigate directly to `myUiApp/Access/Login`, the cookie appears on first load every time. The proxy is not strictly necessary, but it makes our lives a lot easier at the moment so I am hoping to find a solution that works without removing it.

Comment: weird...have you consider switching from Azure Functions proxy to API Management (consumption plan)?

Comment: I hadn't considered that. Based on a little research I think the cost would be prohibitive in the near-term, but it could be possible for the future. I'd be worried about this issue still occurring though, since I am not sure what is causing it currently.